# How do I get my current DNS Server in C#?

Tags: c#

How do I get my current DNS Server in C#?

Comment: By your, do you mean the local machine's DNS server, the DNS servers for your domain or something else?  There are many different answers to what is "your DNS Server," IMO.

Comment: I am thinking about converting my unsafe code that performs Mx Record lookup into a safe version.  

See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906615/how-to-get-around-dnsrecordlistfree-error-in-net-framework-4-0

Comment: What I'd like to know is how to perform DNS lookups without having to specify the dns server name, ie have the system use the default. This is what happens any time you type in a URL somewhere, so not sure why the DNS classes cant allow a default value.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See the MSDN on [`IPInterfaceProperties.DnsAddresses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.dnsaddresses.aspx) for sample code.

Answer (score 6):

I was recently trying to do the same thing and found this [excellent example](http://www.robertsindall.co.uk/blog/how-to-get-local-dns-server-address/) by Robert Sindal.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace HowToGetLocalDnsServerAddressConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetDnsAdress());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static IPAddress GetDnsAdress()
        {
            NetworkInterface[] networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

            foreach (NetworkInterface networkInterface in networkInterfaces)
            {
                if (networkInterface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                    IPInterfaceProperties ipProperties = networkInterface.GetIPProperties();
                    IPAddressCollection dnsAddresses = ipProperties.DnsAddresses;

                    foreach (IPAddress dnsAdress in dnsAddresses)
                    {
                        return dnsAdress;
                    }
                }
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to find DNS Address");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For myself since I was actually doing this via powershell (in a place where there was no ipconfig etc) `[System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces() | ? { $_.OperationalStatus -eq [System.Net.NetworkInformation.OperationalStatus]::Up } | % { $_.GetIPProperties().DnsAddresses.IPAddress`

Answer (score 0):

This method determines the configured dns server addresses on all interfaces which are "up". It allows the choice if IPv4 and / or IPv6 addresses are wanted.

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;

public static IPAddress[] GetDnsAdresses(bool ip4Wanted, bool ip6Wanted)
{
    NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
    HashSet<IPAddress> dnsAddresses = new HashSet<IPAddress>();

    foreach (NetworkInterface networkInterface in interfaces)
    {
        if (networkInterface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        {
            IPInterfaceProperties ipProperties = networkInterface.GetIPProperties();

            foreach (IPAddress forAddress in ipProperties.DnsAddresses)
            {
                if ((ip4Wanted && forAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork) || (ip6Wanted && forAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6))
                {
                    dnsAddresses.Add(forAddress);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return dnsAddresses.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added IPHostEntry in case you want to get a few more data such as name, not just the DNS server address.

```
NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(ni => ni.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback&&ni.OperationalStatus== OperationalStatus.Up);

        if (ni.GetIPProperties().IsDynamicDnsEnabled|| ni.GetIPProperties().IsDnsEnabled)
        {
            
            var dnsServer = ni.GetIPProperties().DnsAddresses;

            foreach (var dns in dnsServer)
            {
                IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(dns);
                Console.WriteLine($"DNS server: {dns.ToString()} ({hostInfo.HostName.ToString()})");
            }

        }
```