# Parsing alternate DNS servers from IP config

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract the alternate DNS servers from this snippit from ipconfig /all. Basically, I want to write all the lines between the `DNS Servers` line and the `NetBIOS over Tcpip` line

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0B-AB-37-2D-28
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::edd5:2e2e:6979:5b59%3(Preferred) 
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.91.89(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 67111851
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-B0-7D-38-00-0B-AB-2E-90-1E
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Here's my code for getting the primary DNS server.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Temp\ipconfig.txt");
foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (line.Contains("DNS Servers")
        { 
            txtPreferredDNS = line.Split(':').First();
        }
        // need help getting the alternate DNS servers
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying this? You could [get them with C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906706/how-do-i-get-my-current-dns-server-in-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

1.- find the index where DNS Servers appear:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx

2.- knowing the index

```
   int index = lines.IndexOf('DNS Servers%')
 while (int i=index, i< lines.length, i++){
 if (!line.Contains("DNS Servers"))
       { 
           txtPreferredDNS = line.Split(':').First(); // make it an array 
 instead or a collection
        }
else {
  //change value of i to get out of the loop
 }

}
```

your main problem is that you have assumed that the four DNS servers in your example are in the same line, when they are not.

You can also work out a regular expression to use it, which would be a better solution.