# How to know when Network interface uses router as DNS server in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dns, router

So we all know cmd command 'ipconfig /all'. For example, we have Wi-Fi Network Interface. DHCP is enabled and DNS server is our own router. How could I know if the network interface is using the router as DNS server in C#? In the code, I can get DNS server IPs, and all the other information, but is it possible to know if the router as DNS server?

default class `NetworkInterface` probably won't tell me that... But maybe there is some sort of algorithm to determine that?

Comment: See following codeproject : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/370616/Details-from-any-DOS-based-application

Comment: This is not what I’m asking.

Comment: You can use this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906706/how-do-i-get-my-current-dns-server-in-c) and check if the ip is on public or private network

Comment: Didn't you say ipconfig/all gave the results you were looking for?  So doesn't the codeproject implement ipconfig/all?

Comment: @Kalten : What does public of private have to do with a router as a DNS Server?

Comment: Why do you care what type machine is being used as the DNS Server?  The Title of the posting and what you are asking seem to be different.   What are you calling a router?  A DNS server can be any where on the Network as long as there is a route from the Local PC to the DNS Server.  To find out if there is a direct connection or there is more than one hop you would have to use PING and check the TIME TO LIVE. (TTL).

Comment: @jdweng Imagine I know nothing about DNS. How would you tell me from ipfoncig resuult, that DNS server is router itself?

Comment: Why do you care if it is a router?  All you care is the response and that you get a IP address and a route to reqiested machine.

Comment: @jdweng It's so good you know better what should I care about :)

Comment: I am trying to help.  You are asking something that is very unusual.  There may be a better solution and without understanding the issue I cannot help.

Comment: @jdweng if the ip you got is public (like 8.8.8.8) it's not your router. If it's private (like 192.168.XXX.XXX or 10.XXX.XXX.XXX, ...) you have lot of chance that it's your router. You can compare the dns ip with `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() -> networkInterface.GetIPProperties() -> ipProperties.GatewayAddresses -> GatewayAddresses`

Comment: What happens if you are in a Corporate Network and one Office is in New York and the other in Chicago?   You are in Chicago and the DNS Server is in New York?  When using a DNS why are you using IP addresses instead of Computer Names?  Is DCHP enabled?  DCHP IP addresses change approximately once a month and using IP address is considered wrong.  DNS Server is meant to resolve Compter Names to IP Routes.

Answer (score 0):

The `NetworkInterface` class expose lot of data like interface gateway and dns server ip. Just need to check  `gateway ip == dns ip`.  There can be multiple gateway and dns for each interface so you need to find some rule yourself. There, my naive implementation based on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906706/how-do-i-get-my-current-dns-server-in-c):

```
NetworkInterface[] networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

foreach (NetworkInterface networkInterface in networkInterfaces)
{
    if (networkInterface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up && networkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback)
    {
        IPInterfaceProperties ipProperties = networkInterface.GetIPProperties();

        var gateways = ipProperties.GatewayAddresses.Select(ga => ga.Address);
        var dns = ipProperties.DnsAddresses;

        if (dns.Any(d => gateways.Contains(d))){
            Console.Write("dns router found on interface " + networkInterface.Name);
        }
    }
}
```