# How to get around DnsRecordListFree error in .NET Framework 4.0?

Tags: c#, dllimport

I am doing an MxRecordLookup. I am getting an error when calling the DnsRecordListFree in the .NET Framework 4.0. I am using Windows 7. How do I get around it? Here is the error:

```
Faulting application name: MxRecordService.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4ce25848
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16559, time stamp: 0x4ba9b802
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000c6df2
Faulting process id: 0x110c
Faulting application start time: 0x01cb85f46c1140da
Faulting application path: C:\vss\Web\MXRecordWS\MxRecordService\bin\Debug\MxRecordService.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: e8c9ecb6-f1e8-11df-8afe-0026b9777c1c
```

My code is:

```
[DllImport("dnsapi.dll", EntryPoint = "DnsQuery_W", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern UInt32 DnsQuery([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)]ref string hostname, UInt16 iType, UInt32 iOptions, UInt32 aipServers, ref  IntPtr ppQueryResults, UInt32 pReserved);

    [DllImport("dnsapi.dll", EntryPoint = "DnsRecordListFree", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern void DnsRecordListFree(ref IntPtr pRecordList, UInt32 iFreeType);
```

I have tried the post [How to get around DnsRecordListFree error in .NET Framework 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906615/how-to-get-around-dnsrecordlistfree-error-in-net-framework-4-0)

**[Update]**: Finally, fixed it. The solution is try to make sure the win32 struct and c# struct is bit(bit size) mapping. This can be achieved by using exact c# type for win32 type.

Comment: As "Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16559, time stamp: 0x4ba9b802", details are above. Since the exception is from unmanaged code, so i cannot try/catch it; only get an error message in Windows EventLog.

Comment: That error message isn't really helpful. What happens when you add the line `throw new Win32Exception();` after the call to the unmanaged code?

Comment: BTW: Any reason you're not using the [Dns Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.aspx)?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as this. What types did you have to change to get it to work?

Comment: [Update]: Finally, fixed it. The solution is try to make sure the win32 struct and c# struct is bit(bit size) mapping. This can be achieved by using exact c# type for win32 type.

Comment: Thanks but can you give me a bit more detail? Do I just need to make my struct's Int fields bigger or smaller or is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the function DnsRecordListFree definition to:

```
  [DllImport("dnsapi.dll", EntryPoint = "DnsRecordListFree", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern void DnsRecordListFree(ref IntPtr pRecordList, UInt32 iFreeType);
```

**Edit**: I guess there is only one version of this function